# How to place individual tables in the subtable environment each on a separate page?

Tags: tables

Complete beginner here. I have two (landscape) tables that belong together (one caption, each table has its own subcaption). I'm using the `subtable` environment and everything works - apart from one thing. Each subtable contains a lot of data, so I want each placed on a separate page. How do I do this? This is my code:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{N\textsubscript{T} General caption.} 
    \begin{subtable}{1.0\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Caption for first table.} \label{tab1}
        \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} ... p{1.5cm}}
            \hline
            % data
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \\ \\ \\ 
    \begin{subtable}{1.0\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Caption for second table.} \label{tab2}
            \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} ... p{1.5cm}}
                \hline  
                % data
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\ContinuedFloat` from `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{N\textsubscript{T} General caption.}
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Caption for first table.} \label{tab1}
        \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}  p{1.5cm}}
            \hline
            % data
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\clearpage %% only for demo
\begin{sidewaystable}\ContinuedFloat
    \caption{N\textsubscript{T} General caption (cont.). }

    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Caption for second table.} \label{tab2}
            \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}  p{1.5cm}}
                \hline
                % data
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]